# return a key using only a value from firebase in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I'm trying to retrieve the key, using only the value, in Firebase.

Am working in Swift, for IOS

Trying to write a function that would like to return "hey", when given only the users email address "hey@hey.com"

Basically have the value at hand, and would like to retrieve the key, am trying to just delete the entry.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Here's the bit im unsure of.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {

        let friendsSelectedEmail = friendsEmailsFromFirebase[indexPath.row]
        let refToUserFriendList = fir.child("mybuddies").child(userID)
        print(friendsSelectedEmail)

        //query for the key of the email address, then use that to delete the object
        //Or is there an easier firebase method?



        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

**edit

In a nutshell, i just wanna delete this key-value pair, and I have access to only the value(email address), is that doable via a single firebase method? **assuming i dont use the better structure that @jay posted.

Comment: Can you show the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? That will really help us see specifically what the problem is.

Comment: Sure! And thanks too!

Comment: What you think is not actually the key. The key is `zCUnxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxTx2` and rest of part is the value. So your approach is wrong.

Comment: With current DB structure you will have to fetch all email nodes at once by using single observer and need to filter the key based on email locally.

Comment: Does `fir.child("mybuddies").child(userID)` point to the `zCUnK...` node in your screenshot?

Comment: Frank, yes it does. I can find the zCUnk... key. However my intention is to ultimately just delete the whole hey:”hey@hey.com object.  I could be wrong, but firebase requires us to delete it only after specifying the key of key-value?

Comment: @TheTiger The key to the node the user is pointing to is actually *hey*, the *parent key* is the *zCUnxxx...*. Remember everything is key: value pairs. so while the zCUxxx. is a key, and the value being hey: "hey@hey.com" that value is actually a key: value pair in itself

Comment: The bigger question here is why is they *hey* node named *hey* in the first place? If it's going to be named *hey* in every node then what you are doing is simple but it would probably make a more sense to make that key *email* and then you could query all of the nodes under zCU for emails that contain "hey@hey.com*. Is the intention to store the *hey* part of *hey@hey.com* as the key to that node?

Comment: TheTiger, that seems a little inefficient, what is the user has like 100 buddies or something?  However I may follow that approach if there isn’t a better way. Like pulling the entire chunk of email objects into a dictionary then pulling the key out into a another variable then feeding it into the firebase method to delete that little thing. However I’m sure there’s a better way.

Comment: @Jay Yeap! That was my first idea but I realise firebase can not accept keys that contain @, $ or other special characters. Live and learn right?  oh and hey, or test, is actually intended to be the user’s buddy’s name.

Comment: Ah - super easy then... answer coming up

Comment: @Jay Yes I know that.... I actually meant was this is not correct way to achieve what he wants to do. I didn't fully explain it. Firebase contains json data and everything is here is an array or dictionary containing number, string, boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the intention here is to use the *hey* part of *hey@hey.com* as the key.

A better approach is to create the child nodes with childByAutoId and store the properties within that node. So your structure becomes

```
zCu.....
  email: "hey@hey.com"
  buddy_name: "Leroy"
  domain: "hey.com"
```

Then you can simply query all nodes for email that equals "hey@hey.com" which will return a snapshot that also has the user_name (hey) and domain (hey.com if needed)

If you need the code for that query, let me know. Keep in mind Firebase is asynchronous so it doesn't really "return" a value. You work with the value within the closure following the query.

From a comment, it appears we want to remove the buddy_name and email but leave the node. If the node is known, you can just create that reference, otherwise you can query for it. Either way you'll get the parent key to the node

```
let buddyRef = parent_node_key.child("buddy_name")
let domainRef = parent_node_key.child("domain")

buddyRef.setValue("")
domainRef.setValue("")
```

Keep in mind that I left email in this case as if we delete that, then the entire node will go away; a node must have at least one value to exist.

To add some clarity;

To create that structure, you would need to know the users uid which is used as a key or if you want it in another node, use .childByAutoId to create the key.

```
let ref = thisUsersUid  //or let ref = your_firebase.childByAutoId()
ref.child("email").setValue("hey@hey.com")
ref.child("domain").setValue("hey.com")
ref.child("buddy_name").setValue("Leroy")
```

Comment: The “hey” is actually the buddy’s name. Doesn’t really have any Co-relation to the email address. The user selects the buddy’s email address from a table view and would like to delete it.  Let’s say the user would like to delete the hey away (also the whole key-value pair), given only the email address. I’m wondering if there is a firebase method that allows that.

Comment: Basically like.. given a value, insert that value into a firebase method to delete the key-value pair.

Comment: I updated the structure to reflect a buddy_name. In this case it's Leroy. Query your node for the email address *hey@hey.com* and delete the returned node.

Comment: Or like.. given the string “Leroy” delete buddy_name and email:”hey@hey.com” while leaving domain:”hey.com” intact.

Comment: yeap! That’s the part. So gotta query first yeah? To get the key. Then after that, will use the key to delete the node.  I sincerely appreciate your help man. I was just hoping firebase had a method that allowed deletes without inputting the key.

Comment: Sure. Same structure. Updated answer to remove those child nodes. There's no reason to not use a key, but if you already have it you don't need to query for it. i.e. if the key is the current users uid for example, you can get that within code without a query.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jay. I really appreciate. Just didn’t wanna use the unique ids and all, wanted to keep it simple since all that’s needed is just the email address. The name field was just to keep it unique too. But I’ll follow your structure just in case there’s extra stuff needed in the future. It’s way cleaner too. Thanks man!

Comment: My pleasure. Using the unique id's really keeps is very simple since it guarantees every node is unique, makes them highly queryable and can be used as a reference to that node across your app and structure. If the answer helped, be sure to accept it so it can help others.

Comment: For the sake of curiosity, or lets say i wanna be lazy in this case, is there an easy firebase method to delete a single key value pair, inputting just the value?

Comment: What does 'inputting just the value' mean? Does it mean query Firebase for a value the user supplies? How do you or the user get that value? Deleting a single key: value pair is very easy (as shown in the answer) so it's not being lazy (lol) but it is crafting your code and Firebase structure to match what the desired output is.

Comment: Cause I have access to the actual string “hey@hey.com” which the user selects from the table view. So I kinda just wanna insert that value (“hey@hey.com”) into a firebase method to delete the thing. However the firebase methods seem to require the key (“hey”)  string to be input instead to be able to delete it. Just wondering if I am missing something.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Suppose you've got a string "Hello, World" and want to store it in code. How would you do it? You would say That's Easy! Just assign it to a string variable *let myString = "Hello, World"* so myString is the *key* and the "Hello, World" is the *value*. Likewise, suppose you want to store that same string in in SQL Database. Where would it go? It would need to be added as a row for a particular column; *INSERT INTO my_table (Strings, Said_By) VALUES ('Hello, World', 'My Computer')* so the *Strings* and *Said_By* columns are the keys. What is your key?

Comment: It’s like.. firebase is asking me to input the key (“hey”) in the method which deletes the value (“hey@hey.com”). However I have access to only “hey@hey.com”, and would like to use that in a firebase method instead.

Comment: When I created this structure it was .child(buddy_name).child(buddy_email). So I suppose the buddy_name “hey”, is the key. And the buddy_email “hey@hey.com” is the value.

Comment: That's correct! Change the buddy name key to 'email', and add another child node with 'buddy_name' as the key and their name as the value. Then you can easily delete those nodes with the code in my answer.

Comment: Yeap! I’d have loved to do that, but alas firebase takes no @,$, or other social characters in the key. Hence it’s this way instead.

Comment: You're not using that as a key. Your keys are 'email' and 'buddy_name' and the values will be the email address and the buddys name. Look at my answer for a specific example

Comment: @AndrewPeaShewTher I updated the answer with a little more code to show how the Firebase structure would be created.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped. Accepting answers that give you direction and help solve the issue can also help others with similar issues.